# create an instance of Hub\signalR in AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, service-provider

in my case, messsage are come from internal events. no new request.

is there a way to create an Hub and send data to clients?

storing and resuse old Hub are crached with

> 'object is disposed..'

)

old frameworks has GlobalContext..

I have tried somthing like :

```
DataHub _hub =(DataHub) ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DataHub));
_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("method");
```

but ServiceProvider also disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/signal-r-with-asp-net-core-hosted-service-net-5/
the solution is using BackgroundService with Dependency Injection of `IHubContext`

this instance has long live (for my undestand ,while BackgroundService does not disposed).

```
public class HubMessageService : BackgroundService
    {
        IHubContext<DataHub> _hubContext;
        public HubMessageService(IHubContext<DataHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext ;
        }
```

in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<HubMessageService>();
            ...
```